# Writing a shell script to generate wave files

Tags: shell, ros, festival

I was looking at writing a script to convert the contents of a .txt file to .wav files.

The command that currently does is :

```
text2wave textFileName.txt -o wavFileName.wav
```

So, pretty simple command. It looks at what's inside the .txt file and converts it all to a .wav file. But what I would like to do is have just one .txt that contains a number of lines and each of those lines would be converted to a .wav file. For example : `line 0, line 1, line 2, ... to be converted into 0.wav, 1.wav, 2.wav, ... etc`

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I'm also open to different approaches.

Comment: Each line in .txt converts to 1.wav 2.wav .. respectively. Am I correct ??

Comment: @AshishK Yes, that's correct. I'll edit it to make that more clear

Comment: Sure, and I am writing the script for you. Just a minute

Comment: @AshishK Feel free to post it as an answer, and if possible could you provide some comments explaining how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
filename=/path/to/text/file

while read -r line
do
    echo $line > somefile.txt
    text2wave somefile.txt -o $i.wav
    i=$((i+1))

done < "$filename"
```

I think this would do your job of extracting each line and converting into respective `.wav` file.

Comment: I have tried making it as simple as possible. You can go through it and ping if there is anything that I can make clear for you :)

Comment: Okay this is really legiable. Only line I don't quite understand is `count=`wc -l $text | awk '{ print $1 }'` and I guess the while loop.

Comment: From the count variable I am trying to read the number of lines that are present in the text file. But `wc -l` gives you output in format `<no of lines> <file name>` of which awk gives me only the count.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you're basically getting the i-th line and writing it to somefile.txt and creating a .wav file and then repeating that process for the other lines.

Comment: In while loop I check whether the `i` variable which I am incrementing is below or equal to the `count` and at each iteration it extracts one line from the text file, puts it into `somefile.txt` and converts `somefile.txt` to `.wav`. The `>` character over-writes somefile.txt at each iteration with the content of the next line.

Comment: Absolutely. That is the reason I used `>` and not `>>`

Comment: Got it, it's pretty simple and does the job :) Thank you.

Comment: Okay, I don't know what went wrong but it's sort of working but not really. It creates the correct wave file for the first line, but then from there on it adds all the previous lines and compiles it into the current i.wav

Comment: @marcoNeves are you sure you are using `>` and not `>>`

Comment: Yes, single operand.

Comment: let me check me on my system!

Comment: Sure thing, you might need to install a some external packages though.

Comment: @marcoNeves , I think it's complete and good going now. Actually `head` command is cumulative and takes all the lines `<=` the supplied limit. In this case the `read` command reads each line one by one and stores the value in `$line`. You can futher use this variable `$line` as you wish. Let me know if you have anything else to understand.